# How to resolve "Trying to reopen a closed SQLite database" in android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have been building an android app that uses SQLiteOpenHelper to manage SQLite database. The apps SQLite's database works fine and I can's seem to find any errors, and i checked that i called `new SQLiteOpenHelper().close()` on every SQLite database operation to prevent data leak. But after some months, I get an error telling me that I am trying to reopen an already closed SQLitedatabase. But I double checked everything and I can't seem to find any issues. Am very confused as what could be the problem. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

*Edit*

This is the code that produces the error. Android studio reports error at line where;

`Cursor result = db.rawQuery(selectStmt, null)` exists.

```
public List<DataModel> getAssignmentData() {

        List<DataModel> data = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String selectStmt
                = "SELECT " + COLUMN_ASSIGNMENT_TITLE + ", "
                + COLUMN_SUBMISSION_DATE + ", "
                + COLUMN_ASSIGNMENT_DESCRIPTION + ", "
                + COLUMN_LECTURER_NAME + ", "
                + COLUMN_COURSE_CODE + ", "
                + COLUMN_ATTACHED_IMAGE + ", "
                + COLUMN_ID + ", "
                + COLUMN_SUBMITTED + " FROM " + ASSIGNMENT_TABLE;

        Cursor result = db.rawQuery(selectStmt, null);

        if (result.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String title = result.getString(0);
                String date = result.getString(1);
                String description = result.getString(2);
                String lecturerName = result.getString(3);
                String course = result.getString(4);
                String attachedImages = result.getString(5);
                int id = result.getInt(6);
                boolean submitted = result.getInt(7) == 1;

                AssignmentModel assignment = new AssignmentModel();
                assignment.setTitle(retrieveEntry(title));
                assignment.setDate(date);
                assignment.setDescription(retrieveEntry(description));
                assignment.setLecturerName(retrieveEntry(lecturerName));
                assignment.setCourseCode(course);
                assignment.setAttachedImage(attachedImages);
                assignment.setPosition(id);
                assignment.setSubmitted(submitted);

                data.add(assignment);
            } while (result.moveToNext());

        }
        result.close();
        return data;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Android `SQLiteDatabase` has a simple reference count internally. `new SQLiteOpenHelper()` constructor call does not open the database i.e. increment the reference count, but calling `close()` will decrement it, possibly invalidating a `SQLiteDatabase` reference you have opened for some other reason.

Instead of pairing `close()` with constructor calls, pair them with actual opening of the database, such as `getWritableDatabase()` or `getReadableDatabase()`. We can help you better if you post more code.

Comment: Code is very large and I don't know exactly what to post. I didn't actually call close() on the SQLiteOpenHelper class, but from a subclass SchoolDatabase. So what you are saying is that I should call close for every getWritableDatabase() or getReadableDatabase() call, i.e after using it to perform SQLite operations.

Comment: Something minimal to reproduce your problem would be ideal. Anyway, make sure you only call `close()` when you have actually opened something,

Comment: That's exactly what I am saying. When I used the SQLiteOpenHelper, i closed it properly, Everything works fine, but after some months using the app, it crashes and reports that I was trying to open an already closed database